# Can not build own container

Tags: rhel

How to build redhat 7.1 container ?

I used,

```
FROM redhat:7.1
yum install httpd
```

and, below error I have to face.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Step 0 : FROM redhat:7
```

Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/redhat ... not found

```
Error: image library/redhat:7 not found
```

but when I used FROM `ubuntu`, it's working. So I want to create own `Red Hat`  image. please help me do it....

Comment: You tell us the error you get and we'll have a shot at telling you the reason.  You're going to have to include a lot more diagnostic information in your question.

Comment: FROM redhat:7
RUN yum -y install httpd; yum clean all;
EXPOSE 80 --------------- that is the my Dockerfile. after i build, it not create.

Comment: Are you connected to RHN, which application you want to install on Docker.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected to RHN then this will work.

First try to Get the Docker version

```
# docker version
```

To build:

Copy the sources down and do the build-

```
# docker build --rm -t <username>/httpd .
```

To run (if port 80 is open on your host): You can assign any random port of your choice

```
# docker run -d -p 80:80 <username>/httpd
```

To the port that the container is listening on:

```
# docker ps
```

To test:

```
# curl http://localhost
```

Comment: thanks for your  update. can u tell me how I connect RHN ?